# Deletar um intervalo de linha e coluna no python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Olá. Quero deletar linhas e colunas de um arquivo csv, e ficar apenas com as linhas no intervalo de 15212 até 21777, de um arquivo com mais de 23 mil linhas. As colunas eu consegui deletar da forma que preciso. A questão é, que além de não consegui ficar apenas com esse intervalo, e acabo deletando o head do arquivo tb.

```
import csv

in_file = open("Downloads/Dados_PNBoia/B116353.csv", "r")
out_file = open("Downloads/Dados_PNBoia/B116353_transformed.csv", "w", newline="")
in_csv = csv.reader(in_file)
out_csv = csv.writer(out_file)
for row_number, row in enumerate(in_csv):
if row_number  >= 15221:
out_csv.writerow(row[:10])
in_file.close()
out_file.close()
```

Tentei colocar o between 0 and 15211, mas deu erro.
P.S.: Só para reforçar, está saindo o nome de cada coluna, como 'data', 'lat' etc, e preciso do cabeçalho.
Obrigada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@maynahelena, boa tarde. Tudo bem?

Tomei liberdade de pegar o exemplo do @Cleyton para fazer uma pequena observação, ok?

Cleyton, o seu exemplo resolve o problema, mas ficou faltando um detalhe, pq, sem ele, pelo menos para mim, aparece um erro ***"ValueError: I/O operation on closed file"***. 
Parece que esse erro acontece porque o arquivo é, aberto e pouco tempo depois, é fechado. Com isso, a mudança que fiz para testar inclui o: `with: open(...)`. Logo ao final de `with: open(...) as csvfile:` o arquivo aberto é fechado - Em seguida você entra em um for que tenta gravar nesse arquivo que já foi fechado. Ou seja, coloquei o `for` dentro do `with`. Assim:

```
import csv

in_file = open("Downloads/Dados_PNBoia/B116353.csv", "r")
with open("Downloads/Dados_PNBoia/B116353_transformed.csv", "w", newline="") as csvfile:

    in_csv = csv.reader(in_file)
    out_csv = csv.writer(csvfile)

    for row_number, row in enumerate(in_csv):
        #SE nr linha for igual a 0 (cabeçalho) ou nr linha estiver entre o intervado desejado:
        if row_number == 0 or ( row_number  >= 15221 and row_number  <= 21777 ): 
            out_csv.writerow(row[:10])

in_file.close()
out_file.close()
```

Comment: Para mim, ambos deram certos. Sabe informar se caso queira usar colunas não subsequentes, tipo, colunas 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,34; como devo substituir na linha 'out_csv.writerow(row[:10])', ficaria 'out_csv.writerow(row[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,34])'? Fica dando erro quando faço isso. Abraços

Comment: @maynahelena, uma alternativa seria `out_csv.writerow(row[:8] + [row[34]] )`

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a palavra chave "OR" para filtrar as linhas no IF:

SE nr linha for igual a 0 (cabeçalho) OU nr linha estiver entre o intervalo desejado:

```
import csv

in_file = open("Downloads/Dados_PNBoia/B116353.csv", "r")
out_file = open("Downloads/Dados_PNBoia/B116353_transformed.csv", "w", newline="")
in_csv = csv.reader(in_file)
out_csv = csv.writer(out_file)

for row_number, row in enumerate(in_csv):

  #SE nr linha for igual a 0 (cabeçalho) ou nr linha estiver entre o intervado desejado:
  if row_number == 0 or ( row_number  >= 15221 and row_number  <= 21777 ): 
    out_csv.writerow(row[:10])
    in_file.close()
    out_file.close()
```